# How to overwrite an array of char pointers with a larger list of char pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, cstring, glob

My function is being passed a struct containing, among other things, a NULL terminated array of pointers to words making up a command with arguments.

I'm performing a glob match on the list of arguments, to expand them into a full list of files, then I want to replace the passed argument array with the new expanded one.

The globbing is working fine, that is, g.gl_pathv is populated with the list of expected files. However, I am having trouble copying this array into the struct I was given.

```
#include <glob.h>

struct command {
  char **argv;
  // other fields...
}

void myFunction( struct command * cmd )
{
  char **p = cmd->argv;
  char* program = *p++; // save the program name (e.g 'ls', and increment to the first argument

  glob_t g;
  memset(&g, 0, sizeof(g));
  g.gl_offs = 1;
  int res = glob(*p++, GLOB_DOOFFS, NULL, &g);
  glob_handle_res(res);
  while (*p)
  {
      res = glob(*p, GLOB_DOOFFS | GLOB_APPEND, NULL, &g);
      glob_handle_res(res);
  }

  if( g.gl_pathc <= 0 )
  {
      globfree(&g);
  }

  cmd->argv = malloc((g.gl_pathc + g.gl_offs) * sizeof *cmd->argv);

  if (cmd->argv == NULL) { sys_fatal_error("pattern_expand: malloc failed\n");}
   // copy over the arguments
  size_t i = g.gl_offs;
  for (; i < g.gl_pathc + g.gl_offs; ++i)
      cmd->argv[i] = strdup(g.gl_pathv[i]);

  // insert the original program name
  cmd->argv[0] = strdup(program);
  ** cmd->argv[g.gl_pathc + g.gl_offs] = 0; **
  globfree(&g);
}

void 
command_free(struct esh_command * cmd)
{
    char ** p = cmd->argv;
    while (*p) {
        free(*p++); // Segfaults here, was it already freed?
    }
    free(cmd->argv);
    free(cmd);
}
```

Edit 1: Also, I realized I need to stick program back in there as cmd->argv[0]
Edit 2: Added call to calloc
Edit 3: Edit mem management with tips from Alok
Edit 4: More tips from alok
Edit 5: Almost working.. the app segfaults when freeing the command struct

Finally: Seems like I was missing the terminating NULL, so adding the line:

```
cmd->argv[g.gl_pathc + g.gl_offs] = 0;
```

seemed to make it work.

Comment: So does it work now?  If not, what error do you get?  Also see my most recent edit to my answer.  You are allocating space twice for `paths[0]`, once with `malloc` and then again with `strdup`.

Comment: yea, that code was crufty.. see the latest edit. it is still crashing when accessing the new array..perhaps the \0 characters are getting lost in the shuffle?

Comment: In `cmd->argv[g.gl_pathc + g.gl_offs] = '\0';`, the `'\0'` is equivalent to `0`, which is equivalent to `NULL` here, so you should use `NULL` instead of `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv` is an array of pointers of `char *`.  This means that `argv` has space for `argc` `char *` values.  If you try to copy more than that many `char *` values into it, you will end up with an overflow.

Most likely your `glob` call results in more than `argc` elements in `gl_pathv` field (i.e, `gl_pathc > argc`).  This is undefined behavior.

It is similar to the code below:

```
/* Wrong code */
#include <string.h>

int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int b[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
memcpy(a, b, sizeof b);
```

Solution: you should either work with the `glob_t` struct directly, or allocate new space to copy `gl_pathv` to a new `char **`:

```
char **paths = malloc(g.gl_pathc * sizeof *paths);
if (paths == NULL) { /* handle error */ }
for (size_t i=0; i < g.gl_pathc; ++i) {
    /* The following just copies the pointer */
    paths[i] = g.gl_pathv[i];

    /* If you actually want to copy the string, then
       you need to malloc again here.

       Something like:

       paths[i] = malloc(strlen(g.gl_pathv[i] + 1));

       followed by strcpy.
     */
}

/* free all the allocated data when done */
```

*Edit*: after your edit:

```
cmd->argv = calloc(g.gl_pathc, sizeof(char *) *g.gl_pathc);
```

it should work, but each of `argv[1]` to `argv[g.gl_pathc + g.gl_offs - 1]` is a `char *` that is "owned" by the `struct glob`.  Your `memcpy` call is only copying the pointers.  When you later do `globfree()`, those pointers don't mean anything anymore.  So, you need to do copy the strings for your use:

```
size_t i;
cmd->argv = malloc((g.gl_pathc+g.gl_offs) * sizeof *cmd->argv);
for (i=g.gl_offs; i < g.gl_pathc + g.gl_offs; ++i)
    cmd->argv[i] = strdup(g.gl_pathv[i]);
```

This makes sure you now have your own private copies of the strings.  Be sure to free them (and `argv`) once you are done.

There are a few other problems with your code.

1. You are doing `*p++`, you should do `p++`, since you're not using the value of the dereferencing.
2. You should really check the return value of `glob`.
3. Your `paths` variable needs `g.gl_pathc + 1` elements, not `g.gl_pathc`. (Or more correctly, you need to allocate `g.gl_pathc + g.gl_offs` times `sizeof *paths` bytes.)
4. Your `for` loop to copy strings should be `for (j=1; j < g.gl_pathc + g.gl_offs; ++j)`.
5. Make sure you prevent shell from expanding your glob.  I.e., call `./a.out '*'` instead of `./a.out *`.

Comment: the idea behind my function being passed the command struct is that my function is a handler of sorts that is performing some operation on the command string before it is executed. hence, i need to modify the value of argv in the cmd.

Comment: But where does the `argv` element of `cmd` come from?  If it is an array, you can't just say `cmd->argv = ...`, which is illegal in C.  It is like saying: `int a[] = {1, 2};` followed by `a = malloc(...);`.

Comment: Nevermind, my brain wasn't engaged.  I "missed" the definition of `struct cmd`.

Comment: @Casey: you are not posting your real code.  The `continue;` in the `if` condition doesn't make sense.  Also, try replacing: `glob_t g; memset(&g, 0, sizeof(g));` by `glob_t g = { 0 };`.  Finally, maybe `gl_offs` is only supposed to be written to, not read, so try replacing `gl_offs` by 1 in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to multiple g.gl_pathc by sizeof(char *)?

Comment: hm, yes.. but i think part of the problem is cmd->argv is probably smaller than g.gl_pathv.

after all if the initial argv is made up of two elements: "ls" and "*.h".. the *.h could be expanded into 100s of filenames